# Huawei Mediapad T1 7.0 not Turning On

Tags: tablet, huawei, power-on

I have a problem on my Huawei Mediapad T1 7.0.

It's not turning on. I tried "hard reset" and nothing happens. I also tried poking the reset button below, still nothing. I plugged it on charger but it's stuck with the welcome screen. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? [image: screen where it's stuck]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the firmware, and boot up with your PC. The firmware you can get on Huawei websites.